# How can I use currency formatted?

Tags: javascript, currency

I need one help, in output of JavaScript, I am getting this output:

> 100,000.00

and I want to change it to:

> 100.000,00

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat). It is a very handy native api.

```js
var number = 876543.21;

// German uses comma as decimal separator and period for thousands
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE').format(number));

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'EUR'
}).format(number));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library http://openexchangerates.github.io/accounting.js/
For example:

```
accounting.formatMoney(4999.99, "€", 2, ".", ","); // €4.999,99
```

Answer (score -1):

I think below code will help you to solve the problem. If any further issues let me know

```
  var str = "100,000.00"; 
  var res = str.replace(".", ",");
  document.write(res);
```